# JSON decode function output type with lint package

Tags: json, flutter, types, decode, lint

I am following the offical documentation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inline

```
Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);

print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user['email']}.');
```

When using the lint package from pub.dev I get the error:
A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'.dartinvalid_assignment)

I see the problem that the JSON fields have to be of dynamic type, however, what is the best way to deal with the lint package in this case? Also, the extraction of the decoded fields (i.e. `userName = user['name']`) throws an error because of type mismatch (dynamic vs String for example).

Comment: You have to cast everything related to these maps explicitly. e.g.`jsonDecode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>` or `user['name'] as String`. It's the only way unless you want to loosen the restrictions.